# "I'd like to ask + wh questions" pattern

Tags: sentence-structure

Which sentence is correct if I add a "wh question" after I said "I'd like to ask...".

For example:

> I'd like to ask how much expensive is product A than product B
>
> or
>
> I'd like to ask how much is product A expensive than product B.

---

> I'd like to ask how much these words overlap each other.
>
> or
>
> I'd like to ask how much do these words overlap each other.

---

> I'd like to ask how different these words are
>
> or
>
> I'd like to ask how are these words different

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking. Are you asking differences of degree? Are you asking if your syntax is correct?

Comment: @Peter I meant which sentences are correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask a question indirectly by putting it into a subordinate clause beginning either with "if/whether" or a question word.There's no inversion in the sub clause.

> I'd like to know how different these word are.
>
> I'd like to ask by how much these words overlap each other.
>
> I'd like to ask by how much A is more expensive than B.